# Можно ли на стороне клиента подменить window.location.href?

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго времени суток, господа! Нужно передать в php параметр - текущую ссылку(изначально загруженную), используя window.location.href. Будет ли это безопасно или все же можно изменить переменную передаваемую на сервер?

Сам пробовал изменять адрес, но ничего не получилось, правда, я не уверен, что я использовал все свои знания. В функции javascript пробовал менять передающийся параметр и в строке браузера сам адрес ссылки.

```
 $( ".IDblock" ).click(function() {
  var href = window.location.href;
  $.post('../file.php', {href:href}, 
  function(data) {
  alert(data); });
   });
```

Comment: Адрес меняется следующим образом: `window.location = "http://ru.stackoverflow.com"` т.е  `.href` опускается.

Comment: @Crantisz, мне нужно передать window.location.href на сервер, могут ли его в браузере изменить и отправить другой, или другим каким способом? Мне не нужно его менять на стороне клиента, мне нужно, чтобы мне корректный url пришел.

Comment: @Дмитрий, в браузере доступна отладка. поэтому передать могут что угодно. Более того, запрос на _file.php_ может быть сделан вообще не из браузера

Comment: @Grundy, попытался сейчас сделать запрос к файлу, где идет обработка ничего не получилось, ввел в браузере mysite.com/directory/myfile.php?href=stackoverflow.com, страница даже не загрузилась

Comment: @Grundy, забыл условие в файле поменять, да запрос можно сделать и по-другому, спасибо!